# Cloudflare fails to reach out my vps used nginx settings

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

i'm trying to connect a domain to my vps with cloudflare. both staging and production applications are in one vps. i'm using docker and docker compose to serve them.
by default setting used for http in nginx everything works as expected. i'm using the ip to connect to my app. it is the http configurations:

```
events {}

http {
  upstream c_container_staging {
    server c-container-staging:3004;
  }

  upstream c_auth_staging {
    server c-auth-staging:3005;
  }

  upstream c_bank_staging {
    server c-bank-staging:3006;
  }

  upstream s_auth_staging {
    server s-auth-staging:3001;
  }

  upstream s_user_staging {
    server s-user-staging:3002;
  }

  upstream s_bank_staging {
    server s-bank-staging:3003;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ***.***.***.***;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Backend-Latency $upstream_header_time;
    add_header X-Total-Request-Response-Latency $request_time;
    add_header X-Backend-Connection-Time $upstream_connect_time;
    add_header X-Client-Original-IP $realip_remote_addr;
    add_header X-server-name "bank system";
    add_header X-mode "stg";

    server_tokens off;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/staging.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/staging.access.log;

    location / {
      set $upstream_c_container_staging c_container_staging;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_container_staging;
    }

    location /auth {
      set $upstream_c_container_staging c_container_staging;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_container_staging$request_uri;
    }

    location /bank {
      set $upstream_c_container_staging c_container_staging;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_container_staging$request_uri;
    }

    location /auth/static {
      set $upstream_c_auth_staging c_auth_staging;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_auth_staging$request_uri;
    }

    location /bank/static {
      set $upstream_c_bank_staging c_bank_staging;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_bank_staging$request_uri;
    }

    location /container/static {
      set $upstream_c_container_staging c_container_staging;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_container_staging$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ /api/v\d/auth {
      set $upstream_s_auth_staging s_auth_staging;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_s_auth_staging$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ /api/v\d/user {
      set $upstream_s_user_staging s_user_staging;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_s_user_staging$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ /api/v\d/bank {
      set $upstream_s_bank_staging s_bank_staging;
  
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_s_bank_staging$request_uri;
    }
  }
}
```

but when i use https configurations with my domain name in the nginx file, the browser shows me an error page which is from cloudflare with the 521 error code.
this is the https configurations:

```
events {}

http {
  upstream c_container_prod {
    server c-container-prod:4004;
  }

  upstream c_auth_prod {
    server c-auth-prod:4005;
  }

  upstream c_bank_prod {
    server c-bank-prod:4006;
  }

  upstream s_auth_prod {
    server s-auth-prod:4001;
  }

  upstream s_user_prod {
    server s-user-prod:4002;
  }

  upstream s_bank_prod {
    server s-bank-prod:4003;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2;

    server_name www.********.**** ********.****;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Backend-Latency $upstream_header_time;
    add_header X-Total-Request-Response-Latency $request_time;
    add_header X-Backend-Connection-Time $upstream_connect_time;
    add_header X-Client-Original-IP $realip_remote_addr;
    add_header X-server-name "bank system";
    add_header X-mode "prod";

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/********.****/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/********.****/privkey.pem;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/prod.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/prod.access.log;

    location / {
      set $upstream_c_container_prod c_container_prod;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_container_prod;
    }

    location /auth {
      set $upstream_c_container_prod c_container_prod;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_container_prod$request_uri;
    }

    location /bank {
      set $upstream_c_container_prod c_container_prod;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_container_prod$request_uri;
    }

    location /auth/static {
      set $upstream_c_auth_prod c_auth_prod;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_auth_prod$request_uri;
    }

    location /bank/static {
      set $upstream_c_bank_prod c_bank_prod;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_bank_prod$request_uri;
    }

    location /container/static {
      set $upstream_c_container_prod c_container_prod;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_c_container_prod$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ /api/v\d/auth {
      set $upstream_s_auth_prod s_auth_prod;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_s_auth_prod$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ /api/v\d/user {
      set $upstream_s_user_prod s_user_prod;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_s_user_prod$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ /api/v\d/bank {
      set $upstream_s_bank_prod s_bank_prod;
  
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://$upstream_s_bank_prod$request_uri;
    }
  }
}
```

this is the error:[image]

i have to say that when i use both http and https configurations at the same time in the nginx file, the https requests with my domain name (not my ip) reach to my http configurations. it happens insde my code not in the url. for example when i use `https://********.****`, it goes to `https://***.***.***.***`.
for the ssl/tls settings i have used the certbot package.
for the clarifying see this pic:
[image]